# Can phpstorm infer the entity type from \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage()?

Tags: debugging

Curious whether it's possible to get phpstorm to infer entity types when loading them via entity storage, e.g. `\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node)->load(1)`, without needing to use comments.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to declare the variable in a phpDoc style comment

```
/** @var \Drupal\node\NodeInterface $node */
```

your IDE understands also PHP code, like the PHP type operator `instanceof`:

```
$node = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->load(1);
if ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {
  // your code using $node
}
```

Comment: I suppose my point is that a phpdoc or instanceof check are both cases of adding "pointless" code solely for the purpose of telling the IDE that "this is a node," when ideally it could see "oh, you called get storage for 'node', it must be NodeStorage, and anything loaded from here is a node".

Comment: This is a question what you expect, It's always amazing to see how much an IDE understands of a Drupal project solely by analyzing static code without running it.

Comment: @Mrweiner _oh, you called get storage for 'node', it must be NodeStorage, and anything loaded from here is a node_ That doesn't take into account the fact that you can override the storage class/entity class for an entity type easily with `hook_entity_type_alter()`. The code would need to be executed to resolve the actual class that was used, it's not statically predictable

Comment: @Clive hmm, that's a good point. I suppose that's why https://github.com/mglaman/phpstan-drupal added the entity storage mapping. The answer to my question, then, is probably "no," unless there's a way to do something similar